# Where does Fokker-Planck equation comes from?

Tags: probability

Let $dX_t=\mu(X_t,t)dt+\sigma (X_t,t)dW_t$, $X_0=x_0$. Reading [wikipedia], the distribution of $X_t$ is given by $p(x,t)$ that solve
$$\partial _t p(x,t)=-\partial _x[\mu(x,t)p(x,t)]+\partial _{xx}\left(\frac{\sigma ^2(x,t)}{2}p(x,t)\right).$$

Where does this equation comes from ? How can we prove this result ? (I don't see any proof, and it looks to come from nowhere)

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7622/75ee9008cb59ea36ef3907c0e64ea0b3820e.pdf

Comment: Informally: apply Ito's formula to $\delta_x(y)$, take expectation, and differentiate wrt t.

Comment: @user658409: what is the connection with $\delta _x(y)$ ?

Comment: Check 2.1 on http://www.thalesians.com/archive/public/academic/finance/papers/Harrison_2005.pdf It all falls out quite nicely.